# How to read a shapefile(.shp) from HDFS in Python

Tags: pyspark, hdfs, shapefile

I was wondering if I can read a shapefile from HDFS in Python.

I'd appreciate it if someone could tell me how.

I tried to use pyspark package.
But I think it's not support shapefile format.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Create SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("read_shapefile").getOrCreate()

# Define HDFS path to the shapefile
hdfs_path = "hdfs://<namenode-ip>:<port>/<path>/<file.shp>"

# Read shapefile as Spark DataFrame
df = spark.read.format("shapefile").load(hdfs_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

check if this modification works:

```
shapefile_df = spark.read \
              .format("com.esri.spark.shape") \
              .load("hdfs://<HDFS_HOST>:<HDFS_PORT>/<PATH_TO_SHAPEFILE>")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I tried your advice and I got an error as below:

"Failed to find data source: com.esri.spark.shape. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html"

Is it possible to read shapefiles from HDFS?